# Duplicate column with different name

Tags: postgresql

I have a column on my table called `RecordId`.  I want to duplicate this column to a column named `BookId`.  I know I can add column like this:

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD COLUMN BookId;
```

But how do I populate the value from the other column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE products 
SET BookId = RecordId
WHERE RecordId > 0
```